# running java swing fest test when computer is locked

Tags: java, swing, fest

Can the [FEST-Swing](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) (mentioned [here](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/fest-swing-10-gui-testing-made)) test still work if the computer is locked? I did a test, and it didn't work. I think the Swing doesn't paint on the screen because the screen is locked, hence the [FEST-Swing](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) test will not work. Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what "fest-swing" test is. I've never heard of it.

Comment: I think [this](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) is fest. It's a GUI testing framework.

Comment: @Joshua McKinnon: Oops, I forgot to check the link!

Comment: yes, my question is about the Java Swing GUI testing framework. To answer keuleJ's question, it works like Selenium, you tell it to click a button, it will click the button when it is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Windows.  What worked for me was running the tests on a Linux box using Xvfb.

http://fest.codehaus.org/Running+FEST+under+Xvfb